# sql sum() causing doubling of values with left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

The left out join on dbo.SalespersonProject is causing the value for TranAmt to double. I need to sum the legit TranAmt for projects, but adding in the left outer join and SalesPerson02, causes a match an incorrect doubling.

```
SELECT ARDoc.SlsperId AR_Doc_Sls_ID
     , CASE
       WHEN ARTran.TranType = 'CM' THEN SUM(ARTran.TranAmt) * -1
           ELSE SUM(ARTran.TranAmt) 
       END TranAmt
     , MAX(CASE
           WHEN SalesCommOrder = 1 THEN SalesPersonId
           END) Salesperson01
     , MAX(ISNULL(CASE
                  WHEN SalesCommOrder = 1 THEN Percentage
                  END, .03)) Commission01
     , MAX(CASE
           WHEN SalesCommOrder = 2 THEN SalesPersonId
           END) Salesperson02
     , MAX(CASE
           WHEN SalesCommOrder = 2 THEN Percentage
           END) Commission02
     , PJPROJ.project PJ_ID
     , PJPROJ.project_desc PJ_Description
     , PJPROJ.slsperid SME
     , ARDoc.CustId Cust_ID
     , CASE
       WHEN RTRIM(ARTran.InvtId) = 'GRAPHICS' THEN 1
       WHEN RTRIM(ARTran.InvtID) = 'SERVICE CONTRACT' THEN 2
       END InvtID
     , RTRIM(ARDoc.CustId) + ' ' + Customer.BillName Cust_ID_Name
     , CONVERT( DATE, ARTran.TranDate, 101) Doc_Date
     , ARTran.TranType Doc_Type
     , ARTran.RefNbr
     , PJPROJ.start_date
     , SUM(ARTran.ExtCost) ExtCost
     , SUM(ARTran.UnitPrice) UnitPrice
     , SUM(ARTran.Qty) Qty
     , (
        SELECT SUM(b.eac_amount) [Budg Rev]
               FROM pjptdsum b
                    INNER JOIN pjacct a ON a.acct = b.acct
                                       AND a.acct_type = 'RV'
               WHERE ARDoc.ProjectID = b.project) Budget_Rev
     , (
        SELECT SUM(b.eac_amount) [Budg Rev]
               FROM pjptdsum b
                    INNER JOIN pjacct a ON a.acct = b.acct
                                       AND a.acct_type = 'EX'
               WHERE ARDoc.ProjectID = b.project) Budget_EAC
     , so.TotMerch SalesOrderTotal
     , Salesperson.Name
     , ARTran.PerPost
     , PJPROJ.manager2
     , PJEMPLOY.emp_name
       FROM Testnewgroundapp.dbo.ARDoc ARDoc
            INNER JOIN Testnewgroundapp.dbo.ARTran ARTran ON ARDoc.CustId = ARTran.CustId
                                                         AND ARDoc.RefNbr = ARTran.RefNbr
                                                         AND ARDoc.DocType = ARTran.TranType
            INNER JOIN Testnewgroundapp.dbo.Customer Customer ON ARDoc.CustId = Customer.CustId --INNER JOIN @CustomerTab ct

            LEFT OUTER JOIN Testnewgroundapp.dbo.Salesperson Salesperson ON ARDoc.SlsperId = Salesperson.SlsperId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Testnewgroundapp.dbo.PJPROJ PJPROJ ON ARDoc.ProjectID = PJPROJ.project
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Testnewgroundapp.dbo.PJEMPLOY PJEMPLOY ON PJPROJ.manager2 = PJEMPLOY.employee
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                             SELECT h.PerPost
                                  , h.SlsperID
                                  , SUM(h.TotMerch) TotMerch
                                    FROM SOShipHeader H
                                    GROUP BY h.PerPost
                                           , h.SlsperID) so ON ARTran.PerPost = so.PerPost
                                                           AND ARDoc.SlsperId = so.SlsperID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TestCommissions.dbo.SalespersonProject SalespersonProject ON SalespersonProject.ProjectId = PJPROJ.project --AND SalespersonProject.SalesPerson_Id = @ApplicationUserID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TestCommissions.dbo.SalesPerson AppSalesPerson ON AppSalesPerson.Id = SalespersonProject.SalesPerson_Id
       WHERE
             (ARTran.TranType = 'CM'
          AND ARTran.DrCr = 'D'
           OR ARTran.DrCr = 'C'
          AND
              (ARTran.TranType = 'CS'
            OR ARTran.TranType = 'DM'
            OR ARTran.TranType = 'IN'
              ) 
             ) 
         AND ARTran.TaskID NOT LIKE '%60850'
         AND ARTRan.TaskID NOT LIKE '%60900'
         AND ARTran.invtid <> 'TSCINC001'
         AND ARTran.TranClass NOT IN ('F', 'N', 'T') 
         AND ARTran.Acct NOT IN ('2590', '2040', '2037') 
         AND CONVERT(INT, ARTran.Acct) > 1301
         AND CONVERT(INT, ARTran.PerPost) BETWEEN 201504 AND 201504
         AND ARTran.Rlsed = 1
         AND PJPROJ.project IS NOT NULL
         AND artran.cpnyid IN ('R', 'A') 

       GROUP BY ARDoc.SlsperId

              , ARDoc.ProjectID
              , PJPROJ.project
              , PJPROJ.project_desc
              , PJPROJ.slsperid
              , ARDoc.CustId
              , ARTran.InvtId
              , Customer.BillName
              , ARTran.TranDate
              , ARTran.TranType
              , ARTran.RefNbr
              , PJPROJ.start_date
              , so.TotMerch
              , Salesperson.Name
              , ARTran.PerPost
              , ARDoc.CpnyID
              , PJPROJ.manager2
              , PJEMPLOY.emp_name

       HAVING ARDoc.SlsperId = 'bpettit'
       ORDER BY ARDoc.SlsperId, ARTran.PerPost, PJPROJ.project
```

Comment: sum() isn't the cause, it's just showing a symptom. you haven't joined your extra table properly somehow.

Comment: The join is fine, until I flatten the 2 rows into a single row so that row 1, null, 2 null and row null, 3, null, 4 become a single row, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

If an extra joined table has two records per one main record, this makes each main record appear twice in the result set. The following grouping and summing will then sum each value of the main record or another joined table twice.

Temporarily remove the grouping and summing, but keep all the joins and look at the result set. You will then probably see what causes this doubling.